# pandas: list of dictionaries grouped by key from df

Tags: pandas

I have multiple dataframes, such as the following:

```
In [44]: df1
Out[44]: 
   id featureName  featureValue
0    1   20003=foo             1

In [45]: df2
Out[45]: 
   id featureName  featureValue
0    2         bar          15.9
1    1         bar          23.8
```

My goal is to produce a list of dictionaries per the following: `[{'20003=foo': 1, 'bar': 23.8}, {'bar': 15.9}]`

My initial approach is to first append df2 to df1:

```
In [47]: x = df1.append(df2)
Out[47]: 
   id featureName  featureValue
0    1   20003=foo           1.0
0    2         bar          15.9
1    1         bar          23.8
```

Then do a groupby on id.

```
In [64]: grouped = x.groupby(by='id')

In [65]: for name, group in grouped:
    ...:     print group
    ...:         
   id featureName  featureValue
0    1   20003=foo           1.0
1    1         bar          23.8
   eid featureName  featureValue
0    2         bar          15.9
```

But at that point I am stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cols = ['featureName', 'featureValue']
[dict(zip(*g[cols].T.values)) for n, g in df1.append(df2).groupby('id')]

[{'20003=foo': 1.0, 'bar': 23.8}, {'bar': 15.9}]
```